# what does driver : WebDriver mean in an __init__ function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, pytest

I was completing a tutorial on selenium webdrive and I saw this, Does anyone know what is happening, what does driver:WebDrive mean?

```
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self._driver = driver
```

This is the full code

```
class BasePage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self._driver = driver

    def _type(self, locator: tuple, text: str, time: int = 10):
        self._wait_until_element_is_visible(locator, time)
        self._find(locator).send_keys(text)

    def _click(self, locator: tuple, time: int = 10):
        self._wait_until_element_is_visible(locator, time)
        self._find(locator).click()

    def _wait_until_element_is_visible(self, locator: tuple, time: int = 10):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self._driver, time)
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(locator))

    def _find(self, locator: tuple) -> WebElement:
        return self._driver.find_element(*locator)

    def _open_url(self, url: str):
        self._driver.get(url)
```

Comment: `driver: WebDriver` is the syntax for declaring the expected type of a variable.  It means "The variable name is driver, and it should be a WebDriver object".

Answer (score 0):

It simply means the `type()` of the `driver` object which is `WebDriver`.

you can cross-check just by checking its type:

```py
def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
    print(type(driver))
    self._driver = driver
```

output:

```
<class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The driver: WebDriver in the **init** function is a type hint indicating that the driver parameter should be an instance of the WebDriver class or its subclass. Type hints are used for static analysis and documentation purposes, and they don't affect the code's runtime behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's literally the "browser". Or officially from the Selenium's document, "WebDriver drives a browser natively, learn more about it."

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) refers to both the language bindings and the implementations of the individual browser controlling code which is commonly referred to as just **WebDriver**. In short WebDriver drives the browser natively just like an user would either locally or on a remote machine using the Selenium server in terms of browser automation.

Within this `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
    self._driver = driver
```

Here the argument *`driver: WebDriver`* refers to the [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) that the *`driver`* instance is expected to be of type ***WebDriver***.

You can use the [`type()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/) function to returns class type of the `driver` object passed as parameter as follows:

```
print(type(driver))
```

Answer (score 0):

The driver is a WebDriver object, which will refer to the browser. For example Chrome, Firefox or Edge. The code which you have shared seems like some framework code, as it designed own functions over basic selenium functions.